# Why Google Search Console API Only Returns 1,000 Landing pages?

Tags: python, google-api, google-search-console

I'm trying to fetch all landing pages from Google Search console, this is working fine on sites with less that 1,000 landing pages but when I try it on larger accounts, it only ever returns 1,000 results.

The limit with the API is 5,000

Here is my query:

```
       {
         "startDate": str(start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")),
         "endDate": str(end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")),
         "dimensions": [
          "page"
         ],
         "dimensionFilterGroups": [{
             "filters": [
                 {
                 "dimension": "country",
                 "expression": "GBR"
                 },
                 {
                  "dimension": "device",
                  "expression": "desktop"
                  }],
         "rowLimit": 5000}]
        }
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong, if anything?

API Reference: https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/searchanalytics/query

Comment: How old is the data remember webmaster tools doesn't keep data forever if memory services its only three months old.

Comment: Last 90 days of data

Comment: I would check your code then sounds like its not applying the rowLimit property if your only seeing 1000 rows that's default.   try changing it to 1 or something to ensure that its picking it up.

Comment: It says integer value and it works when I set the dimensions to query

Comment: Try adding a "startRow": 0   Might be that the row limit is only recognized if they are both specified.

Comment: Yea I've tried that too

Answer (score 0):

The `dimensionFilterGroups` property has a `groupType` property that you are missing.

The [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/searchanalytics/query) says:

```
{
  "startDate": string,
  "endDate": string,
  "dimensions": [
    string
  ],
  "searchType": string,
  "dimensionFilterGroups": [
    {
      "groupType": string,
      "filters": [
        {
          "dimension": string,
          "operator": string,
          "expression": string
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "aggregationType": string,
  "rowLimit": integer,
  "startRow": integer
}
```

Since you have no `groupType` perhaps it is giving results to a default query and thereby ignoring your `rowLimit` property.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting only 1000 records out of 4000 so I put this noow I am able to get all data.

```
pageSize:5000,
```

Comment: So how did you figure it out?

Comment: Just tried to change its default value (1000) to 5000 , and in my response i got my all rows which is around 4200